# Azure AD application: how to remove uploaded certificate using microsoft graph API?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

1. I uploaded x509 certificate for Azure AD app while creating using graph API.
   Post request for create application: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications

Request body:

```
{
            "displayName": "APPName",
            "keyCredentials": [
                {
                    "type": "AsymmetricX509Cert",
                    "usage": "Verify",
                    "key": "LS0tLS1UNBVEUtLS0tLQ=="
                }
            ]
        }
```

certificate is getting uploaded successfully.

2. Now, i want to remove/delete uploaded certificate.
   I found "application: remove key" method as mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-removekey?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Is it necessary to add key using "application: add key" to use "application: remove key"?

3. Is it necessary to provide "proof" of possession in the request body of "application: remove key" method?

As, very less amount of documentation is available, i am not able to find these answers.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Q3: If you use API :`application: remove key`, `proof` is necessary.

For Q2: If you want to remove certificates that you have uploaded, there is another way much easier:

```
Request URL:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<-application obj ID->

Request Header:
Authorization: Bearer <-access token->
Content-Type: application/json

Request Body:
{
  "id":"<-application obj id->",
  "keyCredentials":[]
}
```

Just as below:
[image]

Result:
[image]

As you can see, you can overwrite `keyCredentials` property with the JSON value you want by this API.

Pls let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: Hi Stanley, this is a very easy method to remove uploaded certificate.It was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @PoojaDabhade Glad to know it is helpful :)